# Postgres: set client encoding default

Tags: postgresql, utf-8

When querying from certain tables, I'll often receive the error:

```
character with byte sequence 0xef 0xbf 0xbd in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"
```

Varying bytes, but you get the idea. I can  solve this by doing:

```
set client_encoding to 'UTF8';
```

But the (very) annoying thing is, I have to do this client_encoding set every. Single. Time. I open postgres. How do I set this to default?

Also, I am not asking how to change the encoding of a table's data, or of databases I create from now on--that's a different issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also set it as a default for any user or role (takes effect after a new connection is established):

```
ALTER ROLE <rolename> SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the environment variable [PGCLIENTENCODING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) in the operating system or include the `set` command in [.psqlrc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN96655) if you only need it for `psql`

Comment: I actually already have  "SET client_encoding = 'UTF8'; " in my psqlrc.conf file, which is located where that doc specifies. Must have come from my trying to fix this problem originally... but I'm still seeing it.